# Validate items in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a data item I am editing in a table in AngularJS (v1.x) using an `ng-repeat`, where the data consists of a name and a date from/date to.

```
var myPersons = [{
        name: "John Smith",
        coverFromDate: "05/13/2016",
        coverToDate: "05/15/2016"
    },
    {
        name: "Fanny Schmelter",
        coverFromDate: "05/16/2016",
        coverToDate: "05/18/2016"
    }
];
```

I have added validation on the two date changes to ensure that the date from is before the date to using a directive which nicely displays error message in the row.

I want to add some validation on the list to ensure that there is no overlapping dates entered in the entire list.  If there is, I want an error message to appear (ideally alongside the invalid items) and the form to be marked as invalid (to prevent submit).

I am a bit stumped on the best way to do this.  If anyone has a solution then I'd be keen to see - the same logic can be applied to ensure unique person name so don't fret about using dates - its the mechanism I am interested in - should this be a directive separate to the controller, or should it be a controller method etc.  Can it be triggered after a delay on a date from/to field?

I've looked for answers but have pretty much not found anything for 2 days.

I've created a Plnkr for this [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/QF7OVl?p=info).

**UPDATE**

I stumbled upon this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909167/angularjs-how-to-check-for-unique-inputs-and-if-there-is-a-duplicate-mark-both).  This seems to make the controller aware of the view.

I've reworked the above plnkr to have a solution by adding a validate within the controller [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JUQCw1?p=preview).  Is this the best way to do things in the Angular world?  It seems to me like the controller becomes more view aware - ie knows the name of the fields and aware of the form validation methods.

Comment: no overlapping dates means? You mean one person selected dates should not match with the other?

Comment: It seems you need to run through all the data, which means your only option is to use for loop

Comment: @My_Perfect - overlapping dates means that if the range essentially intersects another range.

Comment: @Maanus Indov - ive just added a link to a "solution" based on another SO link.  Personally I think it feels kind of dirty and hacky.

Answer (score 1):

```
 don't fret about using dates
```

Not sure what u mean here, because the rest of ur description seems to suggest, you are trying to solve a date-related problem.

To identify if there are duplicate keys like coverToDate, you can do something like this in ES6

```
let myPersons = [{
        name: "John Smith",
        coverFromDate: "05/13/2016",
        coverToDate: "05/15/2016"
    },
    {
        name: "Fanny Schmelter",
        coverFromDate: "05/16/2016",
        coverToDate: "05/18/2016"
    },
    {
        name: "Plankton",
        coverFromDate: "05/16/2016",
        coverToDate: "05/18/2016"
    }
];

let arr = [];

myPersons.forEach(function(item) {
    let a = item['coverToDate'];
    let b = item['name'];
    let set = new Set(arr);

    if (!set.has(a)){
      arr.push(a);
      console.log(`added ${b} with ${a}`);
    }
    else{
      console.log(`ERROR: ${b} has duplicate ${a}`);
    }
});
```

u can put the validation into the service/factory wrapper, to make it reusable. You should be able to achieve its equivalent using lodash's methods like .every, .forEach, .partial, .has in ES5.

I would recommend use of ng-messages for any additional validation checks

Comment: I was meaning - don't bother with the date checking algorithms.  My question was pertaining to putting the various moving parts in place to have validation working in a nice manner.  I should have emphasised more on I have a list and want to check a modified item against the rest of the items - in my case it was for overlapping dates - but same concept applies to duplicate name checking - ie if I didn't want the name to be duplicated in my scenario.